# Turn a spark DataFrame into a list of each row

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently receiving a spark dataframe and have turned it into a pandas dataframe to make a list of the rows. I want to create the list without making it into a pandas dataframe. Function2 applies a function to a string representation of each row. The column names will not be constant.

```py
def func1(df):
    df = df.select("*").toPandas()
    job_args = [(", ".join(str(i) for i in list(filter(None.__ne__, df.iloc[c].tolist())))) for c in range(0, len(df))]
    results = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(job_args).map(lambda n: function2(n)).collect()
    return results
```

Example:

```
+-----+-----+
|index|count|
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  5  |
|  2  |  9  |
|  3  |  3  |
|  4  |  1  |
```

Becomes

```
rows[0] = [1,5]
rows[1] = [2,9]
rows[2] = [3,3]
rows[3] = [4,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to take all columns in a spark dataframe and concatenate them to a string, then you can do it using these 2 steps:

1. create a new col using [array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array) function and put all the cols inside
2. Use [array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_join) function to concatenate the elements to single string

Here is a working example how to do it:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

l = [(1, 5), (2, 9), (3, 3), (4, 1)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['index', 'count'])

(
  df
  .withColumn('arr', f.array(df.columns))
  .withColumn('str', f.array_join('arr', ', '))
  .select('str')
).show()

+----+
| str|
+----+
|1, 5|
|2, 9|
|3, 3|
|4, 1|
+----+
```